# err Connecting to Google PostgreSQL from PHP App Engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine

My LOCAL proxy is able to connect to Google's PostgreSQL however once deployed on app engine I get

> could not find driver

I have followed the instructions outlined [on Google's how to's](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql-postgres#setting_up_your_local_environment) for the LOCAL proxy which again I've been able to get to connect. For the dsn configuration I've tried to mimic the method used in their [getting-started-PHP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/blob/master/2-structured-data/src/DataModel/Sql.php) where they use a "getPostgresDsn" function. You can read it with the link above.

The script I'm using to try and establish a connection is:

```
<?php

//I've tried the commented section and it also doesn't work when deployed
//$dsn = "pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=postgres";
$dsn = "pgsql:host=/cloudsql/portal-212515:us-central1:myinstance;port=5432;dbname=postgres";

$username = "postgres";
$password = "mypassword";

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

I've made sure

- 'Cloud SQL' API is enabled
- Both app engine and PostgreSQL are under the same project
- Service account has been added as an owner of the project

When reading the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine) is says

> you can connect only by using the instructions linked below

Since PHP isn't listed under "App Engine standard environment to PostgreSQL" does that mean it's impossible to connect from that environment?

I'm really having a hard time with this one and would love it if anyone could maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong. Please and thank you.

Comment: I've gone on the presumption that it can't be done so I've given up on this and used mySQL instead.